# jQuery class DOM

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following:

```
$(".action_btn").click(function(){

}

echo '<a class="saved action_btn x" mid="' . $itemId['MID2'] .'">Saved</a>';
          }else
            echo '<a class="save action_btn" mid="' . $itemId['MID2'] .'">Save</a>';

          echo '<a class="action_btn recommend_btn" act="recommend" href="recommend.php?mid='. $recommended_movie['MID'] .'">Recommend</a>';
```

I have three different `<a>` tag, however I want only the one with class `class="action_btn recommend_btn"` to execute this jQuery. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".action_btn.recommend_btn").click(function(){
    // ...
}
```

For more on Class selectors see both [the w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) and [the jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

you can specify with comma separated in the same way you did

```
$(".action_btn.recommend_btn").click(function(){

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) - which would target all elements with either `class="action_btn"` or `class="recommend_btn"` as opposed to elements with both `class="action_btn recommend_btn"`?

Comment: No, this would select everything with either of the classes, the question was to select only elements with both classes set.

Answer (score -1):

Change your click binding to:

```
$(".action_btn .recommend_btn").click(function(){

}
```

Comment: @scolbal , i think we need a comma or without space ,

Comment: Without the space. The space is effectively the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

Comment: No, this would select all `.recommend_btn` with an ancestor of `.action_btn`.

Comment: My bad, really should test before posting!